# Sending log files to server after Android app crashed

Tags: android, api, logging, crash

I have an Android app, and I'm able to log the crash details in a text file. I want to show a message after an app crash, and I need to send the log file to the server. Any suggestions will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest [Fabric](https://fabric.io).

Fabric is now free! It is famous crash log analytics service. It supports Crash report, Daily user amount statistics... so on.

Or, if you want your own log server, use [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra)

See this to setting your ACRA backend.
https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/Backends

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate Application crash report for Android(ACRA) with your application. So many application on play store using this and very helpful. You can send data based on your requirement.

The main benefit is you can set up your own environment for server-side and no dependency on any others.

Check below link for more information.
https://github.com/ACRA/acra